# Pyglet player won't play

Tags: python, audio-streaming, pyglet

I'm writing an audio player in python using pyglet's Player class. This module is just a test of the Player and Source classes and it produces nothing. No sound, no error, just one warning about vsync that probably has nothing to do with the actual problem.

```
import pyglet.media as media
def main():
  fname='D:\\Music\\JRR Tolkien\\LotR Part I The Fellowship of the Ring\\01-- 0001 Credits.mp3'
  src=media.load(fname)
  player=media.Player()
  player.queue(src)
  player.volume=1.0
  player.play()
if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

Also, src.play() does nothing too. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've also confirmed that the `media.driver` is the `media.drivers.directsound` module. I was afraid it was using `silent`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to somehow start the pyglet loop. Besides drawing the screen, calls the event handlers and plays the sounds.

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.media as media
def main():
    fname='D:\\test.mp3'
    src=media.load(fname)
    player=media.Player()
    player.queue(src)
    player.volume=1.0
    player.play()
    try:
        pyglet.app.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        player.next()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Something like that works, but if you use Pyglet also sure you'll want to draw something.

Comment: OK, I tried that but now it freezes right after `player.play()` not reaching print statements I placed after `pyglet.app.run()` and `player.next()` still without error.

Comment: I'm now running `pyglet.app.run` in a `Thread` and printing `player.time` continuously but that shows zeroes so it must not be playing at all.

Comment: The example works for me. Try to create a pyglet Window, and your print statements will be reached when you close the window. Do you have AVBin installed? Does it work with a wav file?